# JavaFx assign data from serial port

Tags: java, javafx, serial-port, javafx-8

I am writing/reading from serial port with my java fx application. All is fine until I read the data from port. Once I received the data I pass it to the method thats located in my controller for processing. After passing the data to the method in controller I am trying to assign it into my textboxes but it throws NPE exception. I even tried with  Platform.runLater() but still gives me the same NPE message. Any help please?

```
//Serial data reader
@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED)
        return;
    packet = event.getReceivedData();
    // Also tried this myController.processData(packet); Still NPE
    Platform.runLater(()->
    {
        settingsController.processData(packet);
    });
}


//The method in myController
 @FXML
private JFXTextField dataTextField;

public void processData(int[] packet) {

            dataTextField.textProperty().setValue(String.valueOf(packet[2]));  //Here it throws NPE due to dataTextField
            //dataTextField.textProperty().setValue(String.valueOf(5)); Also tried  a dummy value to find out if it is text field or the packet data. I confirmed it is NPE of dataTextField
            //I also tried this .Still the NPE. Also tried with combobox. so no hope
             Platform.runLater(()->
            {
                dataTextField.textProperty().setValue(String.valueOf(packet[2])); 

            }); 
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Somebody marked this as duplicate. It is not the same thing. In the public void processData(int[] packet){       dataTextField.setText("test")           }  // this works fine but it does not work with the data that returns from port read.

Comment: something wrong in the code you are not showing as I already suggested a couple of hours ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
dataTextField.setText(String.valueOf(packet[2]));
```

Also check if the text field in the fxml file is assigned the same `fx:id=dataTextField`.

Post the full stack trace